# Fill the grid from 1 to 100

Tags: code-golf

In this challenge you are supposed to fill a grid 10x10 with numbers from 1 to 100 (each number once) following this rules:

- Number 1 must be on the bottom row
- Number 100 must be on the upper row
- Two consecutive numbers must be one next to the other (diagonals doesn't count)
- The grid must be *random*

It's not necessary at all that all possible outcomes are equiprobable. Still, though, there must be a non-zero chance for every possible grid (that satisfies the first 3 conditions) to occur.

I don't want time to be a problem, but to avoid pure brute force, answers should take less than a minute to run.

Since output shouldn't be the main focus of the challenge I give complete freedom on how to write it, as long as each row in the output corresponds to a row in the grid and numbers are separated by a character (of any kind).

Comment: By "random", do you mean that every grid that satisfies the first 3 conditions has a non-zero chance of being produced? Also, can solutions keep producing random grids until they find one that fits the criteria, or is there a time bound?

Comment: How should output be presented? Does if have to be a string that gives the grid appearance, or can it be a 2x2 array as a functon return value, for example? If the former, 0 (or 00) to 99 would look neater. That one 3-digit number is a pain aesthetically

Comment: Less than a minute to run on what?

Comment: As it, this allows the cheap solution of generating a random grid, outputting it if it satisfies the properties, and otherwise outputting a fixed grid that works.

Comment: What if it takes less than a minute for most cases, but longer for some?

Comment: Albert, do you have a working solution?

Comment: What would you consider as *brute-force* here? Why do you think this can be solved (under all the given conditions) in less than *one minute*?

Comment: @flawr I think one minute is rather short, but í have an algorithm that **might** work in that time based on building a maze starting at the corners (requires some development though. ) Xnor's point is valid but I think what he mentions would be "I know it when I see it" kind of cheating. I'm not sure these are reasons enough to close the question.

Comment: I'd suggest taking this challenge to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) so it can get more feedback before you post it.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt It's not cheating at all when it satisfies the rules of the question. I shouldn't have to judge the asker's intent to decide whether a solution method is fair.